# Custom graphQL scalar LocalDateTime

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java

I am using graphql-spring-boot-starter to create GraphQL API. AFAIK there is not exist default LocalDateTime scalar so I would like to create my custom. I tried to do it this way:

```
 @Bean
public GraphQLScalarType dateTimeType() {
    return new GraphQLScalarType("LocalDateTime", "DataTime scalar", new Coercing() {
        @Override
        public String serialize(Object input) {
            LocalDateTime date = (LocalDateTime) input;
            return   date.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime parseValue(Object input) {
            return LocalDateTime.parse((String) input);
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime parseLiteral(Object input) {
            return LocalDateTime.parse((String) input);
        }
    });

}
```

I got exception:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

Could you please tell me how I can handle with dateTime in my project?

Comment: What does this have to do with Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3):

Add Bean

```
    @Bean
    public GraphQLScalarType timestampScalarType() {
        return GraphQLScalarType.newScalar()
                .name("Timestamp")
                .description("Timestamp scalar")
                .coercing(new Coercing() {
                    @Override
                    public String serialize(Object input) {
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
                        return formatter.format((Date)input);
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public Object parseValue(Object o) throws CoercingParseValueException {
                        return o;
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public Object parseLiteral(Object o) throws CoercingParseLiteralException {
                        return o.toString();
                    }
                })
                .build();

}
```

Add Config

```
@Bean
public RuntimeWiringConfigurer runtimeWiringConfigurer() {
    return wiringBuilder -> wiringBuilder
            .scalar(ExtendedScalars.GraphQLLong)
            .scalar(ExtendedScalars.Date)
            .scalar(timestampScalarType());
}
```

Add graphql file

```
scalar Timestamp
......
createdAt: Timestamp
updatedAt: Timestamp
deletedAt: Timestamp
```

Comment: It's not necessary to register method timestampScalarType as a bean in this case.

Answer (score 1):

here is what i did in my project to pass date and time

```
@Component
public class DateScalarType extends GraphQLScalarType {
public DateScalarType() {
    super("Date", "Date TIME", new Coercing() {
        @Override
        public Object serialize(Object o) throws CoercingSerializeException {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
            return formatter.format((Date)o);
        }

        @Override
        public Object parseValue(Object o) throws CoercingParseValueException {
            return o;
        }

        @Override
        public Object parseLiteral(Object o) throws CoercingParseLiteralException {
            if (o==null){
                return null;
            }
            return o.toString();
        }
    });
}}
```

in graphqls file

```
scalar Date

type example {
creationDate:Date! }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think after providing SchemaParserOptions with a adjusted configuration of mapper it works:

```
    @Bean
public SchemaParserOptions schemaParserOptions(){
   return SchemaParserOptions.newOptions().objectMapperConfigurer((mapper, context) -> {
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }).build();
}
```

GraphQL uses its own objectmapper, therefore you have to register the JavaTimeModule on it.

More information about this for example here: github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/issues/32

Credits to @Florian Schechner @ Dr.Oste